# CS50's Tideman: lock_pairs fails to skip the final pair if it creates a cycle (supposedly)

Tags: c, cs50

I'm stuck at the lock_pairs function of Tideman. I already wrote the code for it and it looks good. It also behaves as it should when running it through the debugger; however, every time I try it with check50 it gives me an error on "lock pair skips final pair if it creates a cycle".
In order to try it out, I've used examples where the final pair is the one which should be skipped and everything goes as planned when I watch the whole process step by step on the debugger, so I really don't know what I'm missing here.

Here's the explanation of the problem: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/3/tideman/

```
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    // When no_cycle is 0, it indicates that there is no cycle and that locking the pair is safe
    int no_cycle = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pair_count; j++)
        {
            // We check each pair, looking for a locked pair where the loser of the pair we're checking is the winner.
            if (!locked[pairs[i].loser][pairs[j].loser])
            {
                no_cycle = 0;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                // If the result is true, we check for a possible cycle using the cycle_check function
                if (cycle_check(i, j) == false)
                {
                    // If the result is false, we lock the pair and move on
                    no_cycle = 0;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    // If the result is true (indicating a cycle), we change the value of no_cycle to avoid locking the pair
                    no_cycle = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (no_cycle == 0)
        {
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
        }
        else continue;
    }
    return;
}

bool cycle_check(i, j)
{
    // We check if the loser of the locked pair is the same as our pair's winner or starting point (the end of the chain is also the begining)
    if (pairs[j].loser == pairs[i].winner)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        //If it isn't, we go through each locked pair, following the chain which could lead to the cycle
        for (int h = 0; h < pair_count; h++)
        {
            if (locked[pairs[j].loser][pairs[h].loser])
            {
                // Once we find the next link in the chain, we start over
                j = h;
                if (cycle_check(i, j) == true)
                {
                    // Once we find that there is indeed a cycle, we break recursion
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        // If we follow the chain but don't find a cycle, the function returns false and the pair is locked
        return false;
    }
}
```

Been stuck forever on this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Btw, english is not my primary language, so please excuse any grammar errors.

Comment: The only time you need to check for a cycle is when you go to lock the final pair. If locking the final pair would create a cycle -- don't lock it. The example given in the directions for PSET3 tideman provides a good example. See [PSet3 - Tideman (one approach)](https://pastebin.com/Ep8V4ZZU)

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand how checking for a cycle before locking each pair would give me a wrong result. Also, if I just check for a cycle on the last pair to be added, wouldn't that create a conflict with check50, since it looks for cycles on middle pairs ("lock_pairs skips middle pair if it creates a cycle")? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't have a cycle until all pairs is locked. This is because you sort the pairs on the strength of the win. You then lock in that order. The [tideman instructions](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/3/tideman/) specify the process in good detail. Start reading beginning with the sentence `"It’s possible, however, that when the arrows are drawn, there is no Condorcet winner. Consider the below ballots."`  I've have seen many other approaches, but stepping through the instructions, this was the simplest way to approach it. The `"To handle this, ..."` paragraph explains he lock order.

Comment: Also, look at the **"Related"** pages to the right. There are 4 additional answers for the tideman algorithm. They also provide a good discussion of the problem, but I've found most overly complicated in the different approaches they take. If you run the code I've provided, compiled with the options provided in the comment at the bottom, using the file included at the bottom (from the tideman instructions example), carefully study the output. It outputs what is taking place, step by step.